# Passing a string reference to a function

Tags: c, string

in my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void build(char *input){



// how do I get the first string "one" here from the *input pointer? and dissect the string - 'one' so that I can get each character separately 
}
int main() {
    const char *strings[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
    printf("1st string is %s\n", strings[0]);
    build(strings);
    return 0;
}
```

My aim of this program is to get each string, say "one", in my build function and separate out each character - 'o' , 'n' , 'e' , and then find a number which is the sum of the ASCII code of  111('o') + 110('n') + 101 ('e') =  322 .(each string may have different length)

```
After compiling others answer I came up with this: Please let me know if this ok?


Possible Answer:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void build(char *input) {

    int i = 0;
    int a=0
    while (*input != '\0') {
        printf("character is %c\n", *input);
        a=a+*input;
        input++;
    }
printf("sum of ascii value of each character is %d\n",a);
    printf("------\n");

}

int main() {

    const char *strings[] = { "one", "two", "three" };

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof strings / sizeof *strings; i++)
        build(strings[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to describe exactly what the problem is with you code: desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: in your program, strings is an array of C-style strings, not just one string!

Comment: [**See here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7803ef188ec6a3d) - that warning isn't by accident. Further, once you pass `strings[0]` as suggested by the answer(s) below, the proper type of parameter for `build` should be `const char *`, not `char*`. You're not modifying the parameter-addressed data, and further you're passing a `const char *` anyway from `main()` once you fix the call to `build`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett...I have edited my question. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 4):

`strings` is actually a pointer-to-pointer-to-char. So calling build() with `strings` parameter is *very* wrong.

There are lots of things wrong here:

1. As a pointer-to-pointer-to-char, you need two dereference operations to access characters. `*strings[0]` (and `string[0][0]`, and `**strings`)is the first character of the first string.
2. The `build()` function wants a pointer to char. And that's fine if you're planning on passing `build()` a string, which it sounds like you want. Maybe? But in the build function you're trying to print the value of a pointer. But that's also fine if that's what you're going for.

Passing strings from an array to a function is easy!
You do it like this:

```
build(strings[0]);
```

Array indices provide one level of dereference, so build() is still getting a char *. From within build(), you can access each character of the string quite simply, like *input, or input[0].

And you absolutely, whenever dealing with strings, compute the length as soon as possible. `build()` should not have to compute the length of the string passed to it.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way that I could pass all the strings at one go to build instead of just passing build(string[0]) ( only the first string) ?

Comment: Yes, but then you're moving all of the logic into another function. If that's your entire program then why even use the other function? The point of functions is to reduce code duplication by programming for the lowest common denominator. It's best to have a loop in main() passing each string to build(), which loops over each character and does its business. Or do whatever :)

Comment: thanks , actually i need have the logic in a separate function because I am just using the main to test my program functionality. You said it is possible to send all the string in one go? can you show me how to do that in my code? Also can you tell me how can I find the length of this string array , if I have send each string to build function using a for loop?

Comment: You can send the `strings` pointer to the function. But you have to modify the function to know what it's accepting. The strlen() function can determine the length of a string. And the sizeof() operator can tell you the length of datatypes. sizeof(strings) returns the entire length of the array of pointers, and sizeof(strings[0]) returns the length of the first index. sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0]) is a common idiom in C to determine the length of arrays with unspecified length at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

First, your parameter types need to match on both the caller and callee side; your's do not. You're passing an array of `const char*` that, when expressed as a parameter, is converted to a pointer-to-first-element. As the element is type `const char *`, the conversion results in `const char **`. But your function is expecting `char *`.

Second. If you're passing a `const char*` to your function, the formal parameter declaration for the `build` function should match. A `char *` can be passed to a function requiring `const char*`; the opposite is not the case. Further I see no reason to pass a non-const parameter regardless, as that function should have no inclinations to modify the data addressed by that pointer.

Next, if you're computing some accumulation of ascii values, you need a place to put that accumulation, and equally important, a mechanism for returning it. The function return result should suffice.

Finally, moving all this into its own function (the loop; not the array) is straight forward. The final result looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int build(const char *s)
{
    unsigned int res = 0;
    for (; *s; res += (unsigned int)*s++);
    return res;
}

void build_all(const char *strings[], size_t N)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int res = build(strings[i]);
        printf("input[%zu] = %s, %u\n", i, strings[i], res);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char *strings[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
    build_all(strings, sizeof strings/sizeof *strings);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
input[0] = one, 322
input[1] = two, 346
input[2] = three, 536
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you expect

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void build(char *input){
int a=0,i;
for(i=0;i<strlen(input);i++)
{
   a=a+input[i];
   printf("%c %d \n ",input[i],input[i]);
}
printf("\n value of a:%d",a);

}
int main() {
int i;
const char *strings[] = { "one", "two", "three"};

for(i=0;i<sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[i]);i++)
build(strings[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I do not understand why 5 is used every where? and what is the reason you made strings[][5] as two dimensional array? Is it possible to do the same thing with out changing the signature of build function like - build(char *input) ?

Comment: The '5' is the length of the longest string in the array of pointers-to-char. This is very bad style. Please do not ever do this! `const char *strings[] = { ... };` is far superior in every way possible. Assess the size of the array of pointers through the `sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0])` construct. In addition, `sizeof(strings)/5` is NOT correct!

Answer (score 0):

It will really all depend where you want to do your processing and what you want `build` to do. If you want `build` to accept a single string (`char *`), then you were approaching the problem correctly. If, as others have pointed out, you want to pass all strings to `build` at once, then you need to adjust the `build` argument list to accept `char**`.

To continue with `build` accepting a single string, then you will need to send each string to build one-at-a-time. Once in `build`, you have your choice to either access each character within `input` using indexes (e.g. `input[0]` to `input[length-1]`) or with a simple character pointer that you can increment to through each position within `input` (e.g. `char *p = input;`, then `*p++` to access each character).

There are many, many ways to do this, here is one relatively simple example that uses a character pointer to walk down the input string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void build (const char *input) 
{
    if (!input || *input == 0) return;

    char *p = (char *)input;
    size_t i = 0;

    printf ("\n  %s (%s):\n\n", __func__, input);

    while (*p)
    {
        printf ("    input[%2zu]:  %c\n", i, *p);
        p++,i++;
    }
}

int main() {

    const char *strings[] = { "one", "two", "three" };

    size_t i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof strings / sizeof *strings; i++)
        build (strings[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/str2build

  build (one):

    input[ 0]:  o
    input[ 1]:  n
    input[ 2]:  e

  build (two):

    input[ 0]:  t
    input[ 1]:  w
    input[ 2]:  o

  build (three):

    input[ 0]:  t
    input[ 1]:  h
    input[ 2]:  r
    input[ 3]:  e
    input[ 4]:  e
```